# Why Magento Catalog/Category model don't save category's data if "Use Flat Catalog Category" is set to "yes"?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm writing a Magento module to manage catalog categories in the main menu for store that have more than 3.5K of categories. For that reason I've set "**Use Flat Catalog Category**" to "**Yes**".

It failed to set/update category's data using magento model (no errors or exceptions found), even though it's working okay if I set "**Use Flat Catalog Category**" to "**No**".

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category = $category->setStoreId($storeId);
$category->load($id);
$category->setData('include_in_menu', 1);
$category->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue:

When Magento is configured to use Flat categories ("**Use Flat Catalog Category**" is set to "**Yes**"), it will need to re-index any updates on the categories.

If it seems that the saved data doesn't appear on the front-end, then it's most probably you need to do:

On the Back-end, open **System**->**Index Management**
select "**Category Flat Data**" and change the index mode to "**Update on Save**". 
Or click the "**Reindex Data**" link of that selection.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this doesn't seem to be working for me unless I disable the flat catalog category in

```
 System / Configuration / (CATALOG) Catalog / (Frontend) Use Flat Catalog Category
```